# Project file not uploading/unseen in solution explorer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

In visual studio community 2022
I already have a different projects in the solution node but, I was going to create a new project being ASP.NET Web API, and upon finding and creating the project, it does not appear in my solution node and my projects remain(3/3) instead of 4/4 projects. What do I do in this situation

Adding a project in the solution node

Comment: First things first, have you tried again? If so and the same thing happened, what EXACT steps did you carry out? Have you looked in the solution folder to see if a folder was created for the project? What exactly does the contents of the solution file look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, at first glance, you have not installed all the ASP.NET Web API development environments. But before I give you a specific solution I have two questions:
1. Is your VS operating environment Windows 11?
2. If you create an ASP.NET Web API project separately, is it successful?

Comment: Sorry a bit of late reply but my computer is running windows 10 as of the moment and here's the problem https://youtu.be/F8P_yVkc9Uo , sorry if I'm not too detailed on explaining I'm still a novice on visual studio community 2022

Comment: In short my version is windows 10 and that I've also tried uploading it to a new project and it really doesn't show

Comment: If you open VS directly, and click create new project. Create an ASP.NET Web API project here, can it be created successfully? If unsuccessful, some error message should appear.

Comment: When creating it loads and in my local file its seen however the solution node does not show it, it short its like this https://youtu.be/F8P_yVkc9Uo

Comment: @JAMAL Please enter dotnet in CMD, will it report ".NET Core SDKs installed: No SDKs were found."?

Comment: I've got to my cmd and it says list-sdks, info, list-runtimes, h|--help

Answer (score 0):

It is preliminarily speculated that there are two dotnet paths in your environment variables. Follow the steps below:

1. Open the environment variable and check whether the following conditions exist:

[image]

2. If there are two or more dotnet paths, please check the correct SDK path
3. Remove redundant dotnet paths that do not exist
4. Open CMD and type "dotnet" to see if it works
5. At this point, if you open the solution again, you should be able to see the project

Considering that you are a novice, you may ignore some error messages. If it doesn't work, please edit the screenshot of your input `dotnet --info` run result in CMD into the post.